# EXIF data for Instagram after rotating image

Tags: java, android, instagram, exif

I use [this](https://gist.github.com/ecdundar/d5b6bdcc2035448fc9cd) method for posting to Instagram from my Android application (yes, i know this is "hack", but still i need it).

Some manufacturers, say, Samsung, saving photo rotated, and with ORIENTATION tag in EXIF.
I used to copy files to my cache "as is", so they were rotated. Now i'm reading EXIF from original file, and use Matrix postRotate method before saving copy.

So here's a tricky part - when i'm posting to Instagram original copy (which is actually rotated 90 degrees), it's ok.
But when i'm trying to post rotated photo (to make it look normal), Instagram returns 400 Bad request.
I tried to copy all EXIF data from original image, and set width, height and orientation according to new file. But it doesn't work.
And if i just make copy of this file (without EXIF), it posts successfully.

Cannot manage this problem, and looking for your help here.

UPDATE:
I found that rotated image has no JFIF tab in Preview info on my Mac, although non-rotated has JFJF tab with density.
Maybe, problem is somewhere there, but i can't find any information about correct transferring JFIF data...